# SharePoint 2013 is compatible with SAML 2.0

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Is SharePoint 2013 compatible with SAML 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer is **NO**

> SAML token-based authentication in SharePoint 2013 uses the SAML 1.1
>   protocol and the WS-Federation Passive Requestor Profile (WS-F PRP).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#plansaml

But interesting, Office 365 support the Saml 2.0

[Announcing support for SAML 2.0 federation with Office 365](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/06/announcing-support-for-saml-2-0-federation-with-office-365/)

Answer (score 0):

No, SharePoint only supports SAML 1.1.